# How to define array as parameter in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, function

I have a function:

```
function recon_mm(lvl, Threshold, fileToCompress)
```

I would like to make `Threshold` an array. I checked the MatLab documentation but could find no clear example how to state that Threshold is an array,

Comment: you don't need to specify it, you can just assume it is. Matlab will handle.

Comment: You should be able to pass `Threshold` to the function just as you've written it. In MATLAB, almost everything in an array by default.

Comment: @AnderBiguri So when I want to invoke `recon_mm` shoudl I write `recon_mm(4,{1,2,3,4}, 'filename.jpg')`? Is it correct invokation? Where 1,2,3,4 are consecutive elements?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. However, remember that an array is something like `[1 2 3 4]` and that `{1 ,2 ,3 ,4}` is a **cell array**. Anyway, you can do that. Thershold can be ANYTHING.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab is not statically typed and does not have syntax for type annotations, but you can check if your parameter is a scalar and return early.

```
if isscalar(Threshold)
    error('Parameter ''Threshold'' must be an array')
    return
end
```

Note that this will also catch 1x1 arrays, e.g. `isscalar([1]) == true`.